# hydra brute force password https

Tags: https, penetration-testing, hydra, penetration-tools

i am having some trouble brute forcing a password on a website in https.
this is the command that i'm using:

```
hydra -l email -P /path/rockyou.txt WEBSITE_IP  http-post-form “_token=6UZ59LAb1LAKF4Z4sdKXGXBMiquzBWYK5tqG6Wwr&email=^USER^&password=^PASS^”
```

but every time i'm starting the process comes out an error message:

```
[ERROR] optional parameter must start with a '/' slash!
```

maybe I using some wrong parameters but i don't know how to proceed.
i'm doing the test on a website in https to check the vulnerabilities and it's first time using hydra, so if you can also link a website where to learn hydra and other tool more it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add slash '/' in your parameter.
Use this command

```
hydra -l email -P /path/rockyou.txt WEBSITE_IP  http-post-form
“/_token=6UZ59LAb1LAKF4Z4sdKXGXBMiquzBWYK5tqG6Wwr&email=^USER^&password=^PASS^”
```